# Alterar precisão de campo numérico SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estou enfrentando um problema ao alterar a precisão de uma coluna numérica em uma tabela SQL SERVER.

O campo está como `NUMERIC(5)` e gostaria de alterá-lo para `NUMERIC(5,2)`, porém está apresentando a mensagem abaixo

Utilizei `ALTER TABLE tabela ALTER COLUMN coluna NUMERIC(5,2);`

- "Erro de estouro aritmético ao converter NUMERIC no tipo de dados NUMERIC".

Esta tabela já possui dados armazenados.

Alguém sabe alguma solução ? Obrigado.

Comment: poste o create table desta tabela.

Comment: Editei minha resposta de verifique se funciona

Comment: Show!! Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente assim irá alterar o tipo da coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ALTER COLUMN coluna NUMERIC(5,2);
```

Para o seu problema especifico creio que o erro não seja o comando SQL mas sim a presença de algum valor que possui 5 casas decimais inteiras e na hora da conversão da erro pois no novo tipo `NUMERIC(5,2)` a 3 casas decimais inteiras.

mude a tabela para

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ALTER COLUMN coluna NUMERIC(7,2);
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, porém já tentei este comando e apresenta aquela mensagem. Esqueci de colocar o comando que eu utilizei. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre devido à especificação de campo numérico do SQL Server, onde o primeiro parâmetro é a quantidade TOTAL de dígitos e o segundo é o quanto desse total é reservado para as casas decimais. Logo, especificando Numerico(5,2) está dizendo para ter no máximo 5 digitos sendo que desses 5, dois serão utilizados para as casas decimais. Como sua tabela já possui dados, um valor 9999 irá estourar o limite de 5 dígitos pois ficará como 9999,00 (6 dígitos). Altere para numérico de 7,2 e seja feliz.